Prove that no maximum/minimum points exist
Use gradient vector and Hesse matrix to find the maximum and minimum points of the following quadratic function and indicate the value of the function at those points: $f (x, y) = x + y^2$.
This is the proof given but I do not understand it: $\lim_{x, y \to \infty} f (x, y) = \infty$.
$\lim_{x \to -\infty \\ y \to 2} f (x, y) = -\infty$
\implies The function has no max or min value.
Can someone explain this to me?

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

It is obvious that no global maximum or minimum exists. The question is referring to local maxima or minima (AKA critical points).

A point $(x, y)$ is the global maxima of a function if $f(x, y) \geq f(a, b) \forall a, b$.
In our case, the function diverges to $+\infty$ as $x$ and $y$ go to $\infty$. As such, the funtion is not bounded above; no matter how you choose your $x, y$, there'll be another point $(a, b)$ such that $f(a, b) > f(x, y)$ (since $f$ isn't bounded above).
As such, no point can be a global maximum since there's another point where the function's output is greater. I.e. no global maximum exists.
The same argument can be applied to why there's no global minima
